# Best way to send user location updates to the server in the background(Android)

Tags: android, service, location

My app needs to send the user location update frequently even when he is not using the app. So I created a service that returns start_sticky and I am using Google location services to send the data as specified here 
[android location updates](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html). My service is implementing ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener So whenever onLocationChanged(Location location) is being called I am sending the location to server. I want to know if doing this way can cause faster battery drain. If so what is the better way to do. While asking this question stackoverflow gave me a warning saying that the question appears subjective amd might be closed. But I cant figure out another way to ask this question. Hope  someone might help me with this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I can think of 2 methods for it:

1- I assume when the location of the user has changed, the app sends the server the lat and lng. So, you can save the lat and lng changes and send a group of them to the server every 20 lat/lng have been collected.

2- You can check if the lat/lng of the location update varies greatly from the previous ones and accordingly you can determine the rate of which you send the data to the server. For example, if the lat/lng are approximately the same, then lower the onLocationChange Listener rate (for instance the user is at home). And when the changes are great, then increase the location listener rate (for instance the user is driving).

However, this all depends on what the data of location is being used for. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks ziad I think the first method doesnt work for me. I will try to implement your second method and let you know